# Transforming time series data before change point analysis in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, change-point

I have count data (non-financial) from 2010-2014 by week.  I am interested in using R and changepoint package to find any significant points of time when the trend changed.  I have two questions about implementing change point given that it is searching to significant change to the mean.  The data is non-stationary (some trends) and additive.

- Should I take the differencing of the count?
- How do I handle the 53 weeks during leap year?